# Testing dependency injection

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection

I am using Dependency Inversion the functional way (ie. using closure instead of protocol/interface/pure virtual) like so:

```
class StatusPoller {
    init(api: @escaping  (String, String) -> Observable<Data>,
         getAccessToken: @escaping () -> String) {
        ...
    }
}

class HeartbeatSender {
    init(api: @escaping  (String, String) -> Observable<Data>,
         getAccessToken: @escaping () -> String) {
        ...
    }
}

class Api {
    func pollStatus(id: String, accessToken: String) -> Observable<Data> {
        ...
    }

    func sendHeartbeat(id: String, accessToken: String) -> Observable<Data> {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now this is the problem. In the dependency injection resolver (Swinject), it goes like this:

```
 container.register(StatusPoller.self) { _ in
            let api = SwinjectApi.container.resolve(Api.self)!
            let authStore = SwinjectAuth.container.resolve(AuthStore.self)!
            return StatusPoller(api: api.pollStatus(id:accessToken:),
                                getAccessToken: authStore.getAccessToken)
 }

 container.register(HeartbeatSender.self) { _ in
            let api = SwinjectApi.container.resolve(Api.self)!
            let authStore = SwinjectAuth.container.resolve(AuthStore.self)!
            return StatusPoller(api: api.pollStatus(id:accessToken:),
                                getAccessToken: authStore.getAccessToken)
 }
```

I accidentally used the same dependency for the API member of different classes. It, fortunately (or unfortunately depending on your POV), worked fine for almost a year now since the backend doesn't really check for the heartbeat consistency (or at all). However, there's a new feature in the last few months that required the checking of the heartbeat of the client all the time now and this caused a bug. I've fixed it after I noticed that the heartbeat is not actually being sent at all because of that mistake above.

So my question is: How do I prevent that in the future? Testing the dependency injection? But, how though? I still don't get how I can make sure that I have injected the correct dependency.

Thanks

EDIT:
To make the question more clear, it's basically the equivalent of this but in functional:

Suppose I have an interface like this:

```
protocol VoipHandlerInterface {
   ...
}

class TwilioVoipHandlerAdapter: VoipHandlerInterface {
   ...
}

class AsteriskVoipHandlerAdapter: VoipHandlerInterface {
   ...
}

class VoipManagerInteractor {
   let voipHandler: VoipHandlerInterface
   init(voipHandler: VoipHandlerInterface) {
      self.voipHandler = voipHandler
   }
}
```

How do I test / make sure that, for instance, I use Twilio instead of Asterisk in `VoipManagerInteractor`?

Comment: You didn't use the wrong dependency. You used the wrong class! You register HeartbeatSender but return a StatusPoller. That compiles? If so I don't see what you can do to save yourself from yourself.

Comment: The problem seems to be everything returns `Observable<Data>` - You need to refactor if possible so that the returns are more specifically typed `Observable<HeartbeatSenderResponse>` or whatever.  The way it is coded now there was nothing to tell the compiler you couldn't inject a `PollStatus`

Comment: @matt Yeah, my mistake. I didn't know what to call it. That compiles, definitely. Using closures as dependencies are usually simpler to use and test. You don't need to mock the whole class to test. We just need to mock that particular closure. However, we do missing the specification form the protocol.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah right. That can be one way to solve it. However, the whole Api class is actually on the Interface-Adapter / Gateway layer of the application (if you are familiar with Clean / Hexagonal / Onion Architecture). Is it alright to add a logic to map the returned Data to each of the API's Response Model into the Interface-Adapter?

Comment: Providing loose coupling between the layers doesn't mean you should have loose types. It doesn't make sense to be able to connect the wrong things between layers; your interfaces shouldn't permit that. The edit to your question is asking something different. `VoipManagerInteractor` shouldn't know or care what type of handler it has been given. In your test harness you just have to get it right. If you are supposed to be testing Twilio but inject an Asterisk handler, then you have just made an error and the system can't help you

Comment: The interfaces should mean that you can't inject, say, an instance of an `InstantMessageHandlerAdapter`; this is more like your original question where you had completely different api functions with the same result type

Comment: @Paulw11 I know that if we use a protocol instead of a closure, the code is bound to a contract declared by the protocol, to its function names. Which is more rigid, organized, and clear. Although we will get the functions from the protocol that we don't even need. While if we use a closure, we are only bound to the pattern of the function (ie. what are its inputs and output) but it's more flexible (we can even use a global static function), and we will only get the needed function. What I meant was how do we make sure that we use the correct implementation? Either using protocols or closures.

Comment: @Paulw11 For example what if from the protocol example, I need to make sure that a certain version of the app should use Twilio and the other use Asterisk? Or in another way, how do I make sure that the dependency injection actually injected the correct object?

Comment: The whole point of dependency injection is that it relies on polymorphism; the object receiving the injection doesn't know or care that the injected object is a twilio handler or an askterisk handler; it just knows it has an instance of voipHandler. You are responsible for ensuring that you injected the correct concrete class. The object receiving the injection can't know because then it would be tightly coupled.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, I guess you're right. BTW, I think I just realized how to test that I should inject the correct object for the dependencies. By using functional / UI tests. Anyway, thank you so much. I think this has been a fruitful conversation.

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with dependency injection. Your unit tests can check if the dependency is used correctly but they can't check to ensure that the correct dependency is passed in. Only integration tests can do that.

The best you can do here is create a UI Testing Bundle for your app and check some minimal functionality to ensure that the correct dependency is passed in. Try to minimize the number of integration tests you need though because they are [brittle and slow](https://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/integrated-tests-are-a-scam).

Lastly, instead of dependency injection, attempt [dependency rejection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/02/02/dependency-rejection/). Make your [boundaries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) value types instead of interfaces.